# Solving "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Given with the query below

```
Select COLUMN_ID,  (Select 
CASE COLUMN_ID
WHEN 4 THEN 'WEIGHT'
WHEN 6 THEN 'CARGO_LENGTH'
WHEN 7 THEN 'WIDTH'
WHEN 8 THEN 'HEIGHT'
END 
GROOVE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS where TABLE_NAME = 'TBL_CARGO')
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS where COLUMN_ID IN(4,6,7,8)
```

I like to get only non blank columns. I'm expecting the output 4 6 7 8 displayed per field. How do I do that?

Comment: Get rid off the in-line view. Do it in single query, no sub-query is required. Post your input and desired output.

Comment: Your subselect returns one row per column in the table TBL_CARGO. It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish - could you please add sample input (or the DDL statement for TBL_CARGO) and expected output?

Comment: Why don't you just select the `column_name` directly ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Lalit Kumar's solved my problem thanks for comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that sub-query and in-line view could be done in single query:

Using **CASE** expression(verbose and easy to understand):

```
SELECT COLUMN_ID,
  CASE COLUMN_ID
    WHEN 4
    THEN 'WEIGHT'
    WHEN 6
    THEN 'CARGO_LENGTH'
    WHEN 7
    THEN 'WIDTH'
    WHEN 8
    THEN 'HEIGHT'
  END GROOVE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TBL_CARGO'
AND COLUMN_ID   IN(4,6,7,8);
```

Using **DECODE**(looks short):

```
SELECT COLUMN_ID,
  DECODE(COLUMN_ID, 4, 'WEIGHT', 6, 'CARGO_LENGTH', 7, 'WIDTH', 8, 'HEIGHT')
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TBL_CARGO'
AND COLUMN_ID   IN(4,6,7,8);
```

Comment: @TDL Glad it helped, please mark it as answered, would help others.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a sub-select, just add the `CASE` expression. Something like this perhaps?

```
Select COLUMN_ID,  
       CASE COLUMN_ID WHEN 4 THEN 'WEIGHT'
                      WHEN 6 THEN 'CARGO_LENGTH'
                      WHEN 7 THEN 'WIDTH'
                      WHEN 8 THEN 'HEIGHT'
       END  GROOVE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
where COLUMN_ID IN(4,6,7,8)
```

Comment: Why did you remove the filter on table_name?

Comment: Good question, I couldn't find out where to move it from the sub-select... Easy to add if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select COLUMN_ID, 
CASE COLUMN_ID
WHEN 4 THEN 'WEIGHT'
WHEN 6 THEN 'CARGO_LENGTH'
WHEN 7 THEN 'WIDTH'
WHEN 8 THEN 'HEIGHT'
END 
GROOVE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS where TABLE_NAME = 'TBL_CARGO'
and COLUMN_ID IN(4,6,7,8)
```